# WCF endpoint not returning WSDL

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I've exposed WCF service on address:

```
http://localhost/service/
```

If I try to get WSDL from that address, it works fine.

I've also added endpoint to the service - and here is the problem. I can't get WSDL from that endpoint. 
I've tried this in the browser:

```
http://localhost/service/en1
```

but it's not returning anything.

I don't understand what is wrong?

My service is quite simple, everything is written in code:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost/service/") });

  ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
  smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
  host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

  host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new BasicHttpBinding(), "en1");

  host.Open();
```

Comment: You also need to set `HttpGetUrl` property of the behaviour, like `smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri(EndpointAddress);`

Comment: Is it possible to set HttpGetUrl for multiple endpoints?

Comment: Well, `HttpGetUrl`is for setting the location of metadata publication, which is usually one per operation contract/service.

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Can you post your comment as answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set `HttpGetUrl` property of the behaviour, like the following:

```
smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri(EndpointAddress);
```

`HttpGetUrl` is for setting the location of metadata publication, which is usually one per service.